# How can i keep a alert om odoo 8 when user entered 0 should show you have entered 0 in the particular slab

Tags: python, odoo-8

How can i keep a alert om odoo 8 when user entered 0 should show you have entered 0 in the particular slab as a popup and when click on OK the record should br saved currently i am getting warning and not saving until the zero is changed .

'

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        accruemonth = {'accrue_jan': 'January', 'accrue_feb': 'February', 
          'accrue_mar':'March','accrue_apr': 'April','accrue_may': 'May', 
          'accrue_june': 'June','accrue_july': 'July','accrue_aug': 
          'August', 'accrue_sep':     
   'September','accrue_oct':'October','accrue_nov':'November''accrue_dec': 
           'December', }
        for key, value in accruemonth.items():
            if 'accrue_slab' in vals and vals['accrue_slab'] == 'monthly' 
                and key in vals and vals[key] < 0.01:
                 raise osv.except_osv(_('Alert!'),
                                     _("%s slab is 0 or empty", )%(value))
```

'
I want to get the record saved when user entered less than 0.01 by showing alert and clicking OK button on the popup window and clicking on save button the record should be saved now i am getting warning as popup window and not allowing to save until we change the value to greter than 0.01.

Answer (score 0):

sree

For this, you have to use the `onchange` method and from there you have to `raise` the `warning` message.
**Example:**

```
def onchange_slab(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if 'Your_Field' < 0:
        return {'warning': {
            'title': _('Warning!'),
            'message': _("slab is 0 or empty")
            }
        }
    return {}
```

Comment: Thank you Can we add   return {'warning': {
            'title': _('Warning!'),
            'message': _("slab is 0 or empty")
            }
        }
    return {} this code in create function

Comment: While adding i am getting  DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "Warning"
LINE 1: ...days_status" WHERE ("hr_holidays_status"."id" in ('Warning')) ...

Comment: why you want to add from creating, you can simply call the change from which field you want to change and warning raise.

Comment: I want  to check for 0 values in fields  by default it will take zero values only its a float field

Comment: Yes, so on the v8 from the XML file that field you can call the onchange method where you check your condition and raise the warning to the user.

Comment: Thabk you i have did that only when i change the values in the field only thee warning is raising i want to check every field is their is any 0 in the fields

Comment: make one method and call from all the fields.

Comment: Hi How can i get the first and last dates of a given month and given year in python 2.7